# I create new Java web project with Vaadin framework.When I extends my class to com.vaadin.Application class the program says "cannot find symbol..."

Tags: java, vaadin

Please help !
I create new Java web project with Vaadin framework.When I extends my class to  com.vaadin.Application class the program says "cannot find symbol..."

```
package com;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;
public class Main extends com.vaadin.Application {
    public void init() {
      Window main=new Window("aa");
        setMainWindow(main);
          }
}
```

Comment: `program says "cannot find symbol..."` Exception/error message is probably the most important part of your question. Please consider posting full message with relevant excerpt from stacktrace if any

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin 7 no longer uses the Application class.
It looks to me as though you are trying to use some Vaadin 6 code in a Vaadin 7 project.